# WooCommerce SKU characters limit

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, sku

I have this question about WooCommerce **`SKU`**: 
Does it have a limit in number of characters? If there is a limit, how to extend it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is not really a limit** as it's stored in WordPress `wp_postmeta` database table in `meta_value` column which limitation is 'long text' corresponding to 4GiB (2^32 - 1) characters *(see below)*.

[image]

Comment: Hehe, and that dialog box is not quite correct.  The limit is 4G _bytes_, not _characters_.  (But you would have other troubles trying to stuff that much into the column.)  A _character_ can occupy up to 4 _bytes_, especially for Emoji.